# Error while installing oh-my-zsh

Tags: zsh

I'm getting an error while installing oh-my-zsh, doing this:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/raw/master/tools/install.sh -O - | sh
```

but at the end i'm getting:

```
/usr/bin/env: zsh: No such file or directory
sh: source: not found
```

what am i doing wrong ?

machine: **Ubuntu 10.10**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For other people who might have problems using oh-my-zsh on ubuntu, here's the solution taken from this gist : https://gist.github.com/1498393

First install zsh :

```
apt-get install zsh
```

Then install oh-my-zsh using zsh :

```
wget https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/raw/master/tools/install.sh -O - | zsh
```

and then you change your shell to zsh

```
chsh -s `which zsh`
```

Make then sure you relaunch your terminal session, no need to reboot

Answer (score 3):

You (probably) don't have zsh installed. You should run `sudo apt-get install zsh` before running the script.

If you have zsh installed, you should do the following:

```
sudo ln -s /bin/zsh4 /bin/zsh
```

This is because Ubuntu doesn't make this at install time, so you have to Do it yourself™.

Anyway, you should update to [Ubuntu 12.04LTS Precise Pangolin](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade), since your version does not have support any more.